# Selenium WebDriver C# Full Website Screenshots With ChromeDriver and FirefoxDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, screenshot, selenium-chromedriver

When I take screenshots with ChromeDriver I get screens with the size of my viewport.

When I take screenshots with FirefoxDriver I get what I want, which is a full screen print of a website.

ChromeDriver is declared like this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

FirefoxDriver is declared like this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Both drivers execute identical code:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);//url is a string variable
ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
Screenshot screenshot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
screenshot.SaveAsFile("c:/test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

ChromeDriver's test.png is of 1920x1099 resolution and contains only the browser viewport.

FirefoxDriver's test.png is of 1903x16559 resolution and contains the whole page.

I know that `GetScreenshot()` method doesn't return identical resolution sizes because it has slightly different implementations in IEDriver, FirefoxDriver, OperaDriver, ChromeDriver.

My questions are:

1. Why is there such difference between ChromeDriver's and FirefoxDriver's `.GetScreenshot()` method, even tho they use an identical interface (ITakesScreenshot)?
2. Is there a way to make ChromeDriver's `GetScreenshot()` method return the whole webpage screen instead of just the viewport?

Answer (score 11):

we can't get the entire page screenshot with ChromeDriver2, we need to go for manual implementation.I have modified a method with is available in a blog which works fine with ChromeDriver.

use this method as following :

```
private IWebDriver _driver = new ChromeDriver(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);
screenshot.SaveAsFile(saveFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

public Bitmap GetEntereScreenshot()
    {

        Bitmap stitchedImage = null;
        try
        {
            long totalwidth1 = (long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript("return document.body.offsetWidth");//documentElement.scrollWidth");

            long totalHeight1 = (long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript("return  document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight");

            int totalWidth = (int)totalwidth1;
            int totalHeight = (int)totalHeight1;

            // Get the Size of the Viewport
            long viewportWidth1 = (long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript("return document.body.clientWidth");//documentElement.scrollWidth");
            long viewportHeight1 = (long)((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript("return window.innerHeight");//documentElement.scrollWidth");

            int viewportWidth = (int)viewportWidth1;
            int viewportHeight = (int)viewportHeight1;


        // Split the Screen in multiple Rectangles
        List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
        // Loop until the Total Height is reached
        for (int i = 0; i < totalHeight; i += viewportHeight)
        {
            int newHeight = viewportHeight;
            // Fix if the Height of the Element is too big
            if (i + viewportHeight > totalHeight)
            {
                newHeight = totalHeight - i;
            }
            // Loop until the Total Width is reached
            for (int ii = 0; ii < totalWidth; ii += viewportWidth)
            {
                int newWidth = viewportWidth;
                // Fix if the Width of the Element is too big
                if (ii + viewportWidth > totalWidth)
                {
                    newWidth = totalWidth - ii;
                }

                // Create and add the Rectangle
                Rectangle currRect = new Rectangle(ii, i, newWidth, newHeight);
                rectangles.Add(currRect);
            }
        }

        // Build the Image
        stitchedImage = new Bitmap(totalWidth, totalHeight);
        // Get all Screenshots and stitch them together
        Rectangle previous = Rectangle.Empty;
        foreach (var rectangle in rectangles)
        {
            // Calculate the Scrolling (if needed)
            if (previous != Rectangle.Empty)
            {
                int xDiff = rectangle.Right - previous.Right;
                int yDiff = rectangle.Bottom - previous.Bottom;
                // Scroll
                //selenium.RunScript(String.Format("window.scrollBy({0}, {1})", xDiff, yDiff));
                ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript(String.Format("window.scrollBy({0}, {1})", xDiff, yDiff));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            }

            // Take Screenshot
            var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot();

            // Build an Image out of the Screenshot
            Image screenshotImage;
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray))
            {
                screenshotImage = Image.FromStream(memStream);
            }

            // Calculate the Source Rectangle
            Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(viewportWidth - rectangle.Width, viewportHeight - rectangle.Height, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);

            // Copy the Image
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(stitchedImage))
            {
                g.DrawImage(screenshotImage, rectangle, sourceRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            // Set the Previous Rectangle
            previous = rectangle;
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle
        }
        return stitchedImage;
    }
```

Comment: There is a small issue when running this script because it takes the control to the browser when scrolling down through webpage because it is a javascript injection. Anyway thanks Roemer :)

Comment: it also having issue with facebook.. or yahoo these wepages shows absolute div at top when you scroll down and that div gets repeated..
any how works fine most of the webpages.

Comment: seems like the width is wrong. I prepared another solution that gets dimensions from the screenshot itself

Comment: I have only been able to get this to work reliably by fixing the height and width with the following:
`totalwidth1 = document.body.scrollWidth.
totalHeight1 = document.body.scrollHeight.
viewportWidth1 = document.documentElement.clientWidth.
viewportHeight1 = document.documentElement.clientHeight.`

Comment: If you are manage to get the correct width and height rest of the code will do the job. Boz different ppl try to get them differently, I think it's depend on the browser the its version.

Comment: Be aware that scaling in Windows must be set to 100% or this won't work! I usually use 150% and scratched my head for a while dealing with it...

Answer (score 11):

I cleaned up @Selvantharajah Roshanth's answer and added a check so that it won't try to stitch together screenshots that already fit in the viewport.

```
public Image GetEntireScreenshot()
{
    // Get the total size of the page
    var totalWidth = (int) (long) ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("return document.body.offsetWidth"); //documentElement.scrollWidth");
    var totalHeight = (int) (long) ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("return  document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight");
    // Get the size of the viewport
    var viewportWidth = (int) (long) ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("return document.body.clientWidth"); //documentElement.scrollWidth");
    var viewportHeight = (int) (long) ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("return window.innerHeight"); //documentElement.scrollWidth");

    // We only care about taking multiple images together if it doesn't already fit
    if (totalWidth <= viewportWidth && totalHeight <= viewportHeight)
    {
        var screenshot = driver.TakeScreenshot();
        return ScreenshotToImage(screenshot);
    }
    // Split the screen in multiple Rectangles
    var rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
    // Loop until the totalHeight is reached
    for (var y = 0; y < totalHeight; y += viewportHeight)
    {
        var newHeight = viewportHeight;
        // Fix if the height of the element is too big
        if (y + viewportHeight > totalHeight)
        {
            newHeight = totalHeight - y;
        }
        // Loop until the totalWidth is reached
        for (var x = 0; x < totalWidth; x += viewportWidth)
        {
            var newWidth = viewportWidth;
            // Fix if the Width of the Element is too big
            if (x + viewportWidth > totalWidth)
            {
                newWidth = totalWidth - x;
            }
            // Create and add the Rectangle
            var currRect = new Rectangle(x, y, newWidth, newHeight);
            rectangles.Add(currRect);
        }
    }
    // Build the Image
    var stitchedImage = new Bitmap(totalWidth, totalHeight);
    // Get all Screenshots and stitch them together
    var previous = Rectangle.Empty;
    foreach (var rectangle in rectangles)
    {
        // Calculate the scrolling (if needed)
        if (previous != Rectangle.Empty)
        {
            var xDiff = rectangle.Right - previous.Right;
            var yDiff = rectangle.Bottom - previous.Bottom;
            // Scroll
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript(String.Format("window.scrollBy({0}, {1})", xDiff, yDiff));
        }
        // Take Screenshot
        var screenshot = driver.TakeScreenshot();
        // Build an Image out of the Screenshot
        var screenshotImage = ScreenshotToImage(screenshot);
        // Calculate the source Rectangle
        var sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(viewportWidth - rectangle.Width, viewportHeight - rectangle.Height, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
        // Copy the Image
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(stitchedImage))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(screenshotImage, rectangle, sourceRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        // Set the Previous Rectangle
        previous = rectangle;
    }
    return stitchedImage;
}

private static Image ScreenshotToImage(Screenshot screenshot)
{
    Image screenshotImage;
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray))
    {
        screenshotImage = Image.FromStream(memStream);
    }
    return screenshotImage;
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I use it for a few months, but now found small bug here. For example if total height is 4 times bigger than viewport, you will get screenshoot consist of 4 images. Lets say you make SS on test fail. If your test fails at bottom of page you will get only bottom part repeated 4 times. It is required to add command to scroll to top at the beggining and it make full page regardless of test stopped at bottom or top or middle of page: `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, 0)")`

Answer (score 4):

It appears as though full-screen screenshots are not yet implemented in the ChromeDriver, due to some inaccuracies in its previous implementation.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294

I have recently written a Selenium based application to test an Internet Explorer UI and found that:

1. Taking screenshots with selenium was not as quick as using .NET, and
2. Selenium is unable to take screenshots when dialog boxes are present. This was a major drawback, as I needed to identify unexpected dialogs during interaction with the pages.

Investigate using the Graphics.CopyFromScreen method in System.Drawing as an alternative solution until the feature is implemented in Chrome. Once you have tried .the Net approach however, I don't think you will look back =]

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled accross the same problem and ChromeDriver2 just does not support it.

So I created a little script which scrolls thru the page, takes screenshots and stitches everything together.

You can find the script in my blog post here:
http://dev.flauschig.ch/wordpress/?p=341

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @kleopatra you were right, the link doesnt work anymore

Comment: It still works, I did not remove it and I can still reach it. Not sure if that information is still valid tho as this was 10 years ago.